# AIDL registerCallback() google docs

Tags: java, android, android-service, aidl

[google docs](http://developer.android.com/guide/components/aidl.html) have a tutorial on how to make an AIDL service. However, when I tried to do the same, I got an error "The method registerCallback(IRemoteInterface) is undefined for the type IRemoteInterface.

I have not seen this "registerCallback" method in any tutorial that I have been googling and my question is why is this not working/why do other places not use it?

I feel like part of my issue is a fundamental misunderstanding about services and their 'callback' to send information to what it is bound to it.
Thanks!

AIDL:

```
package com.mine.ben;

import com.mine.servicenexus.RelPoint;


interface IRemoteInterface {

    Location getLastLocation();
    RelPoint getRelPoint();
    int logControlActivity(in String text,in int severity);
    int getRunningStatus();
}
```

Updated question:
I get a syntax error in my AIDL file when i add

```
void registerCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback);
void unregisterCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback);
```

I have cleaned my workspace and it builds automatically. Is this a problem with the gen file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Few lines from my application:

```
interface IGpsService {
    Bundle getNavigationMessage();
    void resetStatistics();
    void recordingEnable(boolean recordingEnabled, boolean continueLastTrack);
    void registerCallback(IGpsChanged cb);
    void unregisterCallback(IGpsChanged cb);
    boolean isRecordingEnabled();
    void setGhost(int trackId);
    void startGhost();
    void sendUserEvent(int eventId);
}
```

second file for calback interface itself:

```
interface IGpsChanged{
oneway void onLocationChanged(out Bundle message);
}
```

Best of all - **usually you do not need those .aidl definitions**. This is necessary only when exposing service methods outside of the application.

It's also helpful to understand how it works - forst aidl defines basic service's methods. registerCallback is not a "special" method, it's as oridinary as any other, just enables defining callbacks for two-way communication (in this particular case - to send some position info from sesrvice to binded activity (or other component).

As you mentioned in comment - you do not want to create service, just consume some service from outside of application. In that case you need those external aidl file, not the one written by you. Stubs for consuming service's method will be generated in the /gen directory.

Comment: It seems as if our applications are kind of similar. Can you clear something up for me? I have my application and it uses a library that has the service. Does this mean  I need to 'expose service methods' or whatever?(I really do not understand this aidl stuff)

Comment: I've added some clarification at the end of my answer, hope it's clear now ;)

Comment: That definitely helps but could you explain one more thing? I am using that library but I am adding code to add additional functionality. What I want to do with my app is have a service get some information from server(I have that), but the next step is sending it back to the application and I don't know how to do that. Is that through this registerCallback()? Or is there a different way?

Comment: I can't say - it's definetly depends on your library architecture. You just need to see some exapmples for using that library. As I mentioned above "registerCallback" is just convention, not a strictly definded method name for all useages. If you really using *library* you probably do not need to write and use any aidl files (your own or packaged with lib).

Comment: Piotrpo, could you please take a look at this AIDL problem I am having 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955094/aidl-interface-cant-find-import-for-parcelable-class

Answer (score 2):

> google docs have a tutorial on how to make an AIDL service.

That is not a tutorial. It is just ordinary documentation.

> However, when I tried to do the same, I got an error "The method registerCallback(IRemoteInterface) is undefined for the type IRemoteInterface.

That is because you do not have a method named `registerCallback()` in your AIDL.

> I have not seen this "registerCallback" method in any tutorial

It is not in a tutorial. The only occurrences of `registerCallback()` in the Web page that you linked to are from "some sample code demonstrating calling an AIDL-created service, taken from the Remote Service sample in the ApiDemos project". The ApiDemos project is in your SDK installation, if you elected to download sample code from the SDK Manager.

Comment: Thanks for the response. Apologies for the use of 'tutorial'. How do I get this sample ApiDemos project(I can't remember where the install is or what have you). When I tried to put registerCallback into my AIDL I received a syntax error. Is this a good way to do it or is there a better way?

Comment: @bent: "How do I get this sample ApiDemos project" -- as I wrote in my answer, the ApiDemos project is in your SDK installation, if you elected to download sample code from the SDK Manager. "Is this a good way to do it or is there a better way?" -- since I have no idea what "it" is, I cannot answer that. Binding with AIDL is a very advanced technique, needed by ~0.1% of apps, so whatever you are trying to do can probably be done more simply in some other fashion.

Comment: Anyway - if you using the library in your application, and run the service inside your application - you can forget about all those aidl layer. To be more specific - all possible interfaces for binding/unbinding the service, it's callbacks (if exist...) are contained inside the applicaton.

Comment: Okay so perhaps AIDL isn't the right thing for me but because we want to have the ability to later have other applications use the service, we might keep it. However, when i try to add registerCallback to the AIDL file, i get a syntax error. Could you take a look at the updated question?

Comment: @bent: You need to have something named `IRemoteServiceCallback`, it needs to be imported, and you need to name the parameter (e.g., `void registerCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback callback);`).

Comment: !!!!! Thank you CommonsWare. I have posts all over stackoverflow and I am honored to have you help me with my problem, thanks :)

Comment: @CommonsWare could you please take a look at this AIDL problem I am having? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17955094/aidl-interface-cant-find-import-for-parcelable-class

Answer (score 2):

Code example from AIDL guide that you have referenced is taken from [the Remote Service sample in the ApiDemos project.](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/app/RemoteService.java.)
And `registerCallback()` in it is implemented by using  `android.os.RemoteCallbackList<E extends android.os.IInterface>` object.

Answer (score 0):

Make an .aidl file like:

```
package com.example;

oneway interface IRemoteServiceCallback {
    /**
     * Goes to client.
     */
    void valueChanged(int value);
}
```

Make another .aidl file where you import this interface and use it as a method's parameter like:

```
package com.example;

import com.example.IRemoteServiceCallback;

interface IRemoteService {
    /**
     * Goes to service.
     */
    void registerCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback cb);
}
```

- Generate code from .aidl on both sides.
- Implement *IRemoteService.Stub* in service and return it in *onBind()*
- Implement *IRemoteServiceCallback.Stub* in client and pass it in *ServiceConnection*'s *onServiceConnected()* callback to the received from *IRemoteService.Stub.asInterface()* instance of *IRemoteService*.

Now you service can talk back to the client over the passed *IRemoteServiceCallback* implementation.