# AIDL interface can't find import for Parcelable class

Tags: java, import, android-service, aidl

My issue seems to be similar to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14263005/aidl-unable-to-find-the-definition-of-a-parcelable-class) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9277536/cant-use-aidl-files-across-library-projects) but it is a bit different.

I am making an AIDL service that is in a Library project and using it in my application. I have a class Vehicle that is in my application that I have made parcelable so that I can use it in my interface. (I would like to get a List of vehicles from my service that is in the library to my application)

Do I need a Vehicle.java in both the application and the library?

Do I need a Vehicle.aidl in both?

I had Vehicle.java AND Vehicle.aidl in both application and library and I began running into a problem in my application that when I called a method from my interface eclipse wanted me to define it as the Vehicle of the library class and not the application(although they are the same and both parcelable).

```
public List<Vehicle> getVehicles(){...code... }
```

In an effort to resolve this, I tried to make it the application's vehicle class rather than the library's vehicle class in my IRemoteInterface.aidl(in the listed variation below, i get an error that it can't find the import. In other variations like having it be List and no import, it says unknown return type).

```
  package LIBRARY;


import LIBRARY.RelPoint;
import LIBRARY.IRemoteServiceCallback;
import LIBRARY.FleetStatus;
import APPLICATION.Vehicle;


interface IRemoteInterface {

    int getPid();

    void registerCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback callback);
    void unregisterCallback(IRemoteServiceCallback callback);

    List<Vehicle> getVehicles();

}
```

**Here is my parcelable Vehicle class from the application** :

```
package APPLICATION;

import java.util.Date;

import android.os.Parcel;
import android.os.Parcelable;


public class Vehicle implements Parcelable {
    public static final String TAG = "Vehicle";

    long vehicleID;
    long trackID;
    String vehicleName;



     public static final Parcelable.Creator<Vehicle> CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator<Vehicle>() {

            public Vehicle createFromParcel(Parcel src) {
                return new Vehicle(src);
            }

            public Vehicle[] newArray(int size) {
                return new Vehicle[size];
            }

        };



        public Vehicle(Parcel src) {
            readFromParcel(src);
        }

        public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
            dest.writeLong(vehicleID);
            dest.writeLong(trackID);
            dest.writeString(vehicleName);
        }

        public void readFromParcel(Parcel src) {
            vehicleID = src.readLong();
            trackID   = src.readLong();
            vehicleName = src.readString();

        }

        public int describeContents() {
            // nothing special
            return 0;
        }


    public Vehicle() {

    }

    //getter and setter methods below that I removed



}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm reasonably certain you need to have the `Parcelable` classes in the same package on both ends (which is what you end up with by using the one from `APPLICATION` on the library side, I would just do it the other way around). This package has to also be the one declared in the corresponding `aidl` file.

I'd suggest to use a subpackage like `com.example.interop` to make this cleaner (i.e., separate the shared objects in their own package). Both sides should then have a Java file in that package + an `aidl` file that declares it.

Comment: Thanks for coming here! Remove Vehicle class from application? I need to use Vehicle there for other things so does that mean I need to reference Vehicle as LIBRARY.Vehicle?
Is there no way for the Vehicle in Library to use the Vehicle in Application?(I am getting a vehicle from the service and I want to put that vehicle into an SQLite database that I have setup)

Comment: When you say "library", do you mean Android Library or a library package that gets installed? I.e., how many apks does this setup produce?

Comment: A library package that gets installed. It is my boss's code and I am altering it for what I need. I have it set as a dependency or whatever(I have successfully used the library previously for other things)

Comment: So ideally any reference in LIBRARY to Vehicle is APPLICATION's Vehicle

Comment: Can you explain the second part a bit more? Create a package that has Vehicle.java and Vehicle.aidl? Where does this package go(Inside application, library or a new place?)

Comment: Well, either that or use the package from the library on the application side. It really doesn't matter if it's a new package or an existing one as long as it's the same on both ends (and is declared that way in the aidl).

Comment: So I should make a package and put it in both Application and Library? Then I import Vehicle and then use it?

Comment: Cleanest solution IMO, as it's super clear on both sides which objects will get shared through services, so it's easier to think about security, too.

Comment: That makes sense. On the topic of repeating files in both locations... IRemoteInterface.aidl and IRemoteServiceCallback.aidl, should they be in both or only the service?

Comment: Both, since both parties need to know what the interface of the exported service is.

Comment: I have to say @Delyan, you have been beyond helpful once again!

Comment: One more thing! I am getting a "type mismatch" where it is cannot convert from "Vehicle" to "MainActivity.Vehicle" (mainactivity is my main in application)

Comment: SORRY, I did not notice that I had a Fleet.java leftover in my library

Comment: I am stuck by an issue that I am hoping you can help me with. Could you take a look at the SO? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18448216/unable-to-execute-dex-multiple-dex-files-define-lcom-shared-classes Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue and got it working with the following folder and file structure:

1. Under src/main create a directory named "aidl". This is where Android by default looks for .aidl files
2. Under "aidl/" create a directory "com/mypackage/util"
3. Then under "**src/main/aidl/com/mypackage/util**" put the .aidl file of your service and a separate .aidl file of your Parcelable. If the service is called IGetCards then the aidl file **must** be named IGetCards.aidl and if you Parcelable is called Cards then it **must** be in its own file named Cards.aidl.

In src/main/aidl/com/mypackage/util/**IGetCards.aidl**:

```
package com.mypackage.util;

import com.mypackage.util.Cards;

/** Example service interface */
interface IGetCards {

    /** Demonstrates some basic types that you can use as parameters
     * and return values in AIDL.
     */
    Cards getCards();
}
```

In src/main/aidl/com/mypackage/util/**Cards.aidl**:

```
package com.mypackage.util;

parcelable Cards;
```

1. Check each file has a **package statement at the top** and that the service file IGetCards has an import statement at the top importing the Cards class.
2. Now in the Java directory **src/main/java/com/mypackage/util**, put a corresponding **Cards.kt** file which implements the interface. Make sure **Cards.kt has a package statement at the top that matches Cards.aidl.**

In src/main/java/com/mypackage/util/**Cards.kt**:

```
package com.mypackage.util;

class Cards() : Parcelable {
//implement members
...
}
```